# Dynamic memory allocation for integer array in C and free function

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
main () {
    int arr[30];
    int *array;
    int sum = 0;
    int i, j;
    int guidedlen = 10;
    for (i = 0; i < guidedlen; i++) {
        arr[i] = sum + 10;
        sum += 10;
    }
    printf ("\n");
    array = (int *) calloc (guidedlen, sizeof (int));
    for (i = 0; i < guidedlen; i++) {
        array[i] = arr[i];
        array[i] = array[i] + 10;
        printf ("%d ", array[i]);
    }
    printf ("\n");
    memcpy (arr, array, sizeof (int) * guidedlen);
    for (i = 0; i < guidedlen; i++)
        printf ("%d ", arr[i]);
    printf ("\n");
    for (i = 0; i < guidedlen; i++)
        printf ("%d ", array[i]);
    free (array);
    printf ("\n");
    for (i = 0; i < guidedlen; i++)
        printf ("%d ", array[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

I am implementing the above code and I am getting the answer that I want. But after free statement, when I am printing the array. It gives the output: 0 0 40 50 60 70 80 90 100 110. But I think after freeing the array it doesn't hold any previous value. But here the last eight elements are holding the values. Please let me know where is the problem in my code?

Comment: Paying close attention to the line `array = (int *) calloc (guidedlen, sizeof (int));` It could use a bit of thought.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior. What you are doing is illegally accessing the arrays values. When you free the array all it is doing is telling the operating system that you are no longer using that memory. It won't actually change the values in the memory until something else gets allocated on top of that data.

It is similar with the hard drive as well. There is no way to just "delete" the data. If you delete a file it just frees up those blocks to be over written but it won't actually change any of the data. This is how people are able to recover old files that were deleted.

Answer (score 1):

After you free memory you should not assume the memory contents are valid. You no longer 'own' that memory. Accessing it after freeing is illegal. Period.

Answer (score 0):

This Situation is called "Dangling Pointer".

Dangling pointers arise when an object is deleted or de-allocated, without modifying the value of the pointer, so that the pointer still points to the memory location of the de-allocated memory(After freeing the memory, the pointer still points to the same memory location).

After deleting the memory you are not the owner of the memory.So the values in that memory location may changed(If some other process acquires the same memory location) or may not. when you try to print the values in that location, It results in Undefined Behavior.

To avoid the dangling pointer, after freeing the memory make the pointer as `NULL`

```
free (array);
array = NULL;
```

Comment: I got the the proper explanation. Yes it is now showing some memory adresses, but the first two values of the array is showing the value 0.

Comment: @user3901294 first 2 elements is null means, that memory address may be occupied by some other process. That process may change the values in memory location